# Parsing movies in Java

Tags: java, video, media, video-processing, jmf

I'm looking to write a basic movie parser in Java. The movie should be some video file, let's say AVI, and exact times/frames. The program should simply parse the movie according to the data and save it to new files.

It seems like it should be an easy task, but I can't find the right classes in Java to help me. Google is not doing much help either.

Where do I start?

Thanks,
Ariel

Comment: "simply" is unfortunately not the word to use currently about multimedia in Java

Comment: "basic", "simply", " an easy task" - geez, sounds simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with reading about the Java media Framework. [This tutorial](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/) is a bit old but might give you a start.

Unfortunately there is nothing simple about video. Not only are some algorithms patented or not available, there is also a huge amount of containers (like AVI) within which there can be multiple combinations of actual audio and video files. With possibly incompatible bitrates and what not.

You should I think start with reading up a bit about video in general (formats) and decide what you need to support. After that go looking for *your format* in combination with *java*.

Good luck.